# Creating unique variables from array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to make a multiform wardrobe builder I have a session variable for the number of doors the user selected in the previous page (1-6 doors). Based on the number of doors selected I am displaying default doors(i.e no type of door range selected) using a for loop. My issue is that I want each door to have a unique variable and turn these into session variables (to use further in the application) such as door1, door2 and door3 if 3 doors are selected. The idea is for these doors to be unique so the user can click and highlight the door 1 default image and populate that area/image with an image from the list of door ranges. Fairly new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated

code:

```
<?php
$myDoors = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= $selected_doors; $x++) {
    echo "Door: $x <br>";
    $myDoors["Door$x"] = "value set in loop";
      //if you want to loop through them all
    foreach ($myDoors as $key => $val) {
      echo "$key -> $val\n";
    }
    if ($selectRanges == 'Minimalist') { ?>
        <div>
            <img src="images/defaultMinimalist.png" alt="image">
        </div>
    <?php } elseif ($selectRanges == 'Classic') { ?>
        <div>
            <img src="images/defaultClassic.png" alt="image">
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div>
            <img src="images/defaultEllipse.png" alt="image">
        </div>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "Unique variables". `$_SESSION` is an array like any other. You can embed arrays in arrays, so...

```
$_SESSION['doors'][7]['style'] = 'Minimalist';
                  ^^^--- door ID
```

Now it's just a regular array, meaning you don't need to do silly stuff like

```
$id = 7;
$_SESSION["door{$id}"]['style'] = ...
```

Comment: Is door id relative to $selected_doors? i.e. If you have 4 doors will the door id go from 1-4? to further be called. Trying to work it into my code.

Comment: that's up to you on how you assign those ids and build the array.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First create the array of doors and then push the whole array to the session

$_SESSION['doors'] = $myDoors;

now you can access the doors in the session like this

```
$_SESSION['doors'][$doorNumber]
```

Comment: $_SESSION['doors'][$doorNumber] in the loop? How would I add this into my current code? Want to make sure it's right. Thanks